# C++ segmentation fault chrono

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, initialization, declaration, c++-chrono

i am trying to create a little clock for my game-project.
I am using the chrono-high-resolution-clock. 
However, after declaring the variable inside my header file "gameTime.hpp", when referencing it in my source-file "gameTime.cpp", i get a segfault.
Hope anyone can help (and if the answer should be trivial: sorry, but the search i did on the subject didn't help me)
Here is the code:

header-file:

```
class GameTime
{
private:
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point mTime;
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point mLastTime;
    double mTimeSpan;
public:
    GameTime();
    ~GameTime();
    void init();
    double timePassed();
};
```

Source-file:

```
GameTime::GameTime()
{

}

void GameTime::init()
{
    mTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    mLastTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
}

double GameTime::timePassed()
{
    mTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    mTimeSpan = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(mTime - mLastTime).count();
    mLastTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    return mTimeSpan;  
}
```

and the main-function: (it was pointed out that i should include this)

```
double frameTime;
GameTime* gameTime;

gameTime->init();

while(game->running())
{
    frameTime = gameTime->timePassed();

    std::cout << frameTime << std::endl;
}
```

The segfault happens inside the init() function, when i try to set a value for mTime.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You forgot to post code calling those functions (most likely class instance in invalid).

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! I edited my post and included the important parts of my main-function where i call the functions. May the fact that i initialize GameTime via a pointer be the cause of the error? The problem is that if i don't initialize it via a pointer, i get those red lines telling me that the "expression must have pointer type"

Comment: You don't actually create an instance of `GameTime`, and `gameTime` probably doesn't need to be a pointer. Just drop the pointeryness and that should solve your problem.

Comment: @It'scominghome okay, thank you guys! Okay it was an obvious error, but i think i wouldn't have found it alone. I will now answer my question with the solution you made me come up with :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, the problem was that in my main-function, i only created a pointer, but not a real instance of the class GameTime.
The working code now looks like the following:

(main.cpp)

```
GameTime *gameTime = nullptr;

int main()
{
    gameTime = new GameTime();

    gameTime->init();

    while(game->running())
    {
        frameTime = gameTime->timePassed();

        std::cout << frameTime << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In my class-implementations, everything was fine.